# How to show ginput coordinates into real axis value

Tags: matlab, coordinates, ginput

Hi i am trying to extract the coordinates from image (e.g. circle.png attached)
[image]

I use ginput to extract x,y coorinate of my interest (in this case 4 red dots inside the circle)

```
A=imread('circle.png');
figure,imshow(A)
[y,x]=ginput
```

I click on 4 red dots and I got x,y coordinates as below

```
x=134.000000000000
  154.000000000000
  125.000000000000
  136.000000000000


y= 83
   153.000000000000
   170.000000000000
   245.000000000000
```

In this case, x and y coordinates that I got are based on which axis? How can I convert these x and y coordinates to relate into my real data (i.e. I would like to show x axis from 0 to 15 and y axis from 0 to 5)?

Comment: mee mee: This is a harder problem to solve. If you have prior information about how big a pixel is in world coordinates, then it's just a simple scaling from the x and y points to distances. If you don't know what the pixel sizes are, you may want to look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/measuring-planar-objects-with-a-calibrated-camera.html

Answer (score 0):

By default `imshow` hides the tick marks of the axes on which the image is displayed.  To see what the actual axis limits are (and hence how your image is scaled on the axis) you can do

```
>> get(gca,'Xlim')
>> get(gca,'YLim')
```

Or if you'd like to make the axis labels visible then you can do

```
>> h = gca;
>> h.XAxis.Visible = 'on';
>> h.YAxis.Visible = 'on';
```

The `x` and `y` point returned by `ginput` are relative to those axis limits.

Comment: hi Phil, thanks for your advice. I have tried what you suggested but the code generate two figures (one shows just scale (i.e. x and y axis) and one shows the image). Can you please suggest why it happen that way? Sorry for my ignorance. Tks.

Comment: The code you show doesn't generate 2 figures.  What else are you doing?

Comment: I just add the command you suggested. Here it is
    I = imread('circle.png');
    get(gca,'Xlim')
    get(gca,'YLim')
    figure, imshow(I)
    [y,x] = ginput;

Comment: The `get(gca,'XLim')` and `get(gca,'YLim')` needs to be after the `imshow`.